# Prove (local) converse to the implicit function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, inverse

The implicit function theorem tells us that:

*Given a level set $M^k = F^{-1}(F(p_0))$ of a smooth function*

$$F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k},$$

*where $\operatorname{rk}{(Df)(p)} = n-k$ for all  $p$ such that  $F(p) = F(p_0)$, we have that for all $p \in M^k$ there exists $I = \{i_1, \dotsc, i_k\}\subset \{1, \dotsc, n\}$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $M^k \cap U$ is the graph of a smooth function*

$$f: \mathbb{R}^I \to \mathbb{R}^{I^c}.$$

We can state a (local) converse to this:

*Suppose $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that for all $p \in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $M\cap U$ is the graph of a smooth map*

$$f: \mathbb{R}^I \supseteq V \to \mathbb{R}^{I^c} \text{, where } |I|=k.$$

*Then for all $p\in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $W$ of $p$ and a smooth $F: W \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that $M\cap W = F^{-1}F(p)$ and $\operatorname{rk}{(Df(p))}=n-k$.*

In other words, $M$ is locally a level set of a smooth function.

My instructor wrote that the function we should use, given the appropriate neighborhoods, is

$$x \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} \pi_{I^c}(x - f(\pi_{I}(x))),$$

but since $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^{I^c}$, I think he should have written

$$x \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} \pi_{I^c}(x - (f(\pi_{I}(x)), \pi_{I}(x)).$$

My only trouble is showing that $D\phi$ has rank $n-k$. Intuitively it certainly should...notice we can get $x - (f(\pi_{I}(x)), \pi_{I}(x))$ to take any value in $\mathbb{R}^{I^c}$ that we want by wiggling $x$ away from $M$ in any direction. And it would suffice to show that $D\pi_{I^c} = \pi_{I^c}$ has kernel disjoint from the image of the derivative of

$$x \mapsto x - (f(\pi_{I}(x)), \pi_{I}(x)). \tag{2}$$

That seems clear, but what do we know about the derivative of $x \mapsto x - (f(\pi_{I}(x)), \pi_{I}(x))$  that would allow us to say that?

I can see that the partial of (2) in the $I^c$ direction with respect to the $I$ variables will be just those of $f$, because we're just adding a constant to $f$ on this case. But what do we know about the rank of $Df$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the derivative of (2) should be the $(n-k) \times n$ matrix

$$\left[  \begin{matrix} I_{(n-k) \times (n-k)} \mid 0 \end{matrix}  \right],$$

which resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Consider simple situation  where $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. If locally around the origin $0$ we can solve  $F(x,y)=0$ as the  graph $y=f(x)$, then locally $0=   F(x,y)=f(x)-y$. Since  $F'|_x(x,y)=f'(x)$ and  $F'|_y(x,y) = -1$, the rank of $F$ is $1$. We can generalize this.